# How can i create a login view after registration?

Tags: django, django-views

I create models,forms and views for registrarion and i want to create a login view so that after registration user can login.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django_countries.fields import CountryField


g_CHOICES = (('male','male'),('female','female'))

class User(AbstractUser):
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=g_CHOICES,default="male")
    country = CountryField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
g_CHOICES = (('male','male'),('female','female'))


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=g_CHOICES)
    country = CountryField().formfield()
    location = forms.CharField(max_length=30,)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','username','email',
        'password1','password2','gender',
        'country','location']
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    rform = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if rform.is_valid():
        rform.save()
        username = rform.cleaned_data.get('username')
        messages.success(request,('Account created for '+str(username)))
        return redirect('/')
else:
    rform = UserRegisterForm()
return render(request,'reg.html',{'rform':rform})
```

Now i want to create a view for login please someone help

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below one:

```
def login(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
          auth.login(request, user)
          messages.success(request, 'You are now logged in')
          return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
          messages.error(request, 'Invalid credentials')
          return redirect('login')
      else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
```

Or if you are using a django form you can do this way too and this is more preferred way:

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(request,
                                username=cd['username'],
                                password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated '\
                                        'successfully')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: In login.html what i have to give as to redirect my view

Comment: redirect is an optional way, if you dont have a dashboard you can redirect to home page redirect('/'), like this way or you can give a response like this. HttpResponse('Authenticated 'successfully')

Comment: I need a view varible to show the login form in browser...In that view its not there

Comment: you mean you need a template?

Comment: I am getting error at this point   **user_login(request, user)**

Comment: Change to login

Answer (score 1):

You need a view that takes the user's username and password from the POST request, then authenticates them and logs them in using 'authenticate' and 'login' from django.contrib.auth package.

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.views import View

class HandleLogin(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "login.html", {})

    def post(self, request):
        username= request.POST.get("username")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username, password)
        if user is not None:
           if user.is_active:
              login(request, user)
              # Do something for succesfull logged in
           else:
              # Do something else because user is not active
        else:
            # Do something about user not existing
```

For more information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/